# Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, Will $L(V,W)$ be infinite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose *V* is finite-dimensional with $dimV > 0$, and suppose *W* is infinite-dimensional. Will the linear map from *V* to *W* ,denoted $L(V,W)$ ,be infinite-dimensional?

Comment: yes, if $V=\langle v_1,\dots, v_n\rangle$ then $L(V,W)\cong W^n$ which is infinite dimensional (a linear map $V\to W$ is determined uniquely by the image of a basis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Choose an infinite collection of linearly independent vectors $\{w_i\}_{i \in I}$ in $W$.

Pick a basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ for $V$. For $i \in I$, define $T_i: V \to W$ to be the unique linear linear map such that $v_1 \mapsto w_i$ and $v_k \mapsto 0$ for $k \geq 2$.

I claim that $\{T_i\}_{i \in I}$ forms a linearly independent subset of $L(V,W)$, and thus $L(V,W)$ is infinite-dimensional. This should not be difficult, and I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: What if V is infinite dimensional, with: (a) a countable basis, (b) an uncountable basis? Will a similar argument, defining $T_i: V \to W$ to be the linear map such that  $v_1 \mapsto w_i$ and $v_k \mapsto 0$ for $k \neq 0$ work? Is such a definition valid in the first place?

Comment: I think you should mention that you employed the Axiom of Choice to choose an infinite collection of linearly independent vectors in W?